# How can I store the value of an async function to be used multiple times in a function without having to make the async call multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, async-await, promise

I have an async function that makes an API call as so:

```
const getModel = async () => {
  const model = await fetch model...
  return model;
};
```

I also have another function that uses the tfjs model to analyze the sentiment of text:

```
export const analyzeSentiment = async (text) => {
  const model = await getModel();
  const score = await predict(text, model);
  return score;
};
```

My problem is I'm mapping multiple sets of text to the `analyzeSentiment` function, which requires `getModel` to make a fetch call for every set of text. Is there any way to set the return of `getModel()`
to a variable that will persist allowing it to be only called once and used for every time `analyzeSentiment` is called? I have also tried declaring model outside of `analyzeSentiment` and `await`ing it inside the function, however that did not work either. If it matters, I'm using React/Node.

Comment: any function that is `async` returns a Promise ... therefore needs to either be `await`ed or use `.then` ...

Comment: by the way ... since getModel basically returns a Promise which is result of the only (and LAST) awaited function within it ... it's identical in function to `const getModel = () => fetch model...` - and there you see, that you are returning a Promise

Comment: The problem is your `analyzeSentiment()` is too tightly coupled with `getModel()`. Make `model` a parameter to `analyzeSentiment()` if you need it to be shared between multiple calls to `analyzeSentiment()`. Which basically means that when you map multiple sets of text, you might as well just use `predict()` directly.

Comment: "*I have also tried declaring model outside of analyzeSentiment and awaiting it inside the function*" - that should work perfectly (but you likely want to rename the variable to `modelPromise`). Can you show us the code of that attempt, please?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I ended up using the accepted answer's method. What I tried was declaring 'model = getModel()' and doing 'analyzeSentiment = async (await model, text) => ...', however since I was mapping an array to 'analyzeSentiment', 'getModel' was still called every time every time it was required as a paramater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a local cache variable that remembers the value from the first time it was requested and then uses that value from then on:

```
let cachedModel;

export const analyzeSentiment = async (text) => {
  if (!cachedModel) {
       cachedModel = getModel();
  }
  return predict(text, await cachedModel);
};
```

In this implementation `cachedModel` will contain a promise from the first time that `analyzeSentiment()` was called.  If `analyzeSentiment()` is called  multiple times in sequence, the code will still only call `getModel()` once - all the successive calls will just await the same promise.  This all works whether the promise is pending or already fulfilled.

---

Or, if you just want to use the same model for a series of `analyzeSentiment()` calls, but only for that specific series of calls, then get the model once in the caller and pass the same one into a saquence of `analyzeSentiment()` calls as a function argument.